# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory on Ubuntu 16.06

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

Using Ubuntu, am trying to use the scikit-learn examples with this snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Examples of reading texts files and classifying them
"""
from __future__ import division
import datetime
import sklearn.datasets

time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
##from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
######## Reading text files
rootPath = r"/Home/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/"
```

However, I got this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py", line 201, in load_files
    folders = [f for f in sorted(listdir(container_path))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Home/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/
```

I am ery new to Ubuntu and scikit-learn stuff. What could be the issue/error and how do I get it solved.?

[image]

Comment: are you sure the directory exists: `/Home/web2py/corpus/20news-18828`

Comment: yes, I got a snapshot:

Comment: cant get to upload it, sorry

Comment: just copy/paste the text, don't use images. There's probably a case typo. Probably `/Home` doesn't exist. Open a shell and try to locate it.

Comment: AFAIK `Home` isn't a real directory - it's a nautilus bookmark corresponding to the current user's home directory i.e. `~` or (usually) `/home/username`

Answer (score 0):

Thia worked for me:

```
rootPath =os.getenv('HOME/web2py/corpus/20news-18828')
```

However, I got this error:

```
File "/home/mauricewaka/web2py/detscikit.py", line 19, in <module>
    twenty_train = sklearn.datasets.load_files(rootPath,categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py", line 201, in load_files
    folders = [f for f in sorted(listdir(container_path))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Any Ideas on how to get solve this error?
I tried to use encoding='utf-8', or remove the encoding argument but still got the same error